# How to crawl through a website and take screenshots of each page?

Tags: javascript, automation, screenshot, webtrends

My task is to take screenshots of a set of webpages for legal purposes. I'm currently accomplishing this by using [Webshot](http://www.websitescreenshots.com/) and running through its batch operation using a list of URLs I compiled myself. I also have to take screenshots of a rotating Flash banner which is done by using IECapt and its delay function.

Each page has a series of ads that require a screenshot taken of the page they lead to. How can I automate this so that I'm not spending hours clicking on each link after link?

In case that was not clear, the homepage has 4 secondary ads linking to 4 different product pages. I need a screenshot of the homepage (done) and then four different screenshots of the pages that the ads link to.

Oh, and to make things interesting, the homepages use Javascript redirects a la:

```
javascript:dcsOnsiteAdLink('url', '/whyjoin', 'ad', 'S1', 'popup', 'toolbar=yes,location=yes,directories=yes,status=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=780,height=500');
```

Answer (score 6):

Pay someone 3 USD / hour to do it for you through Elance or Mechanical Turk. Even if you'd spend only 4 hours on hacking together a script, that'd cost more than paying someone a few bucks for it.

Comment: This isn't ideal, since as a developer I might be managing a site that has a lot of dependencies and I want to be able to release quickly. I'd suggest trying one of many Casper scripts already made for this or this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/crawl

Answer (score 5):

gnome-web-photo uses the Geko engine to render and take a snap of a web page. It is pretty nifty and scriptable.

Answer (score 3):

Adobe Acrobat Pro is pretty good at this. It can grab an entire site and make it into a single indexed document. Screen shots will only get you what's on the screen, Acrobat Pro can get you the whole page.